# How to split a string if it contains two elements

Tags: python

If a sentence contains more than 2 elements from a and are separated by comma, I want to split the comma.

```
a   = ['benz','bmw','apple','salmon']

sen = "I like benz, but I like bmw more"
```

Code:

```
i=0
for car in a: 
    if car in sen and "," in sen:
        i+=1
if i>1:
    print(sen.split(","))
```

Result:

```
['I like benz', ' but I like bmw more']
```

But if my sentence looks like this:

```
sen="I like benz but I like bmw more, what about you?"
```

Then I don't want to split the sentence because benz and bmw are not separated by comma. Is there any way that I can distinguish if a sentence is structure by **"....[word]"....+","+...."[word]......"?**

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: Do they need to be different words? For example: “I like my bmw, but I like her bmw more”

Comment: @MarkMeyer no :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def split_sentence(sen):
    words   = ['benz','bmw','apple','salmon']

    split = sen.split(",")     #split the string and check if words exists in both sentence
    flag = 0
    for s in split:
        for w in words:
            if w in s:
                flag+=1
                break


    if flag == len(split):
        return split
    return sen

sen="I like benz but I like bmw more, what about you?"
# sen = "I like benz, but I like bmw more"
print(split_sentence(sen))
```

Should return

Case 1:

`I like benz but I like bmw more, what about you?`

Case II:

`['I like benz', ' but I like bmw more']`

Comment: This is neat :) but when the sentence is longer like "I like benz and bmw, she likes apple, what about you?". Then it's hard to split it in this case.

Comment: @Lara19 Yeah. I think it'll work even in that case. All three sentence must contain elements from the list `a` right?

Comment: Not necessary, as long as 2 sentences contain elements, then you can split them. For example, in this case, it will be ["I like benz and bmw","she likes apple, what about you?". But it possibly doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler approach would suffice?

```py
dictionary   = ['benz','bmw','apple','salmon']
sentence = "I like benz, but I like bmw more"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    included_words = [word for word in dictionary if word in sentence]
    if len(included_words) == 2:
        print(sentence, included_words)
```

which outputs:

```
I like benz, but I like bmw more ['benz', 'bmw']
```